# Want to toggle a css class on second element of an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am posting my html code for a list:

```
<ul>
    <li>Notebook</li>
    <li>Jello</li>
    <li>Spinach</li>
    <li>Rice</li>
    <li>Birthday Cake</li>
    <li>Candles</li>
</ul>
```

I want to apply the following css class on each element of the list:

```
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Basically I want to be able to strike it then undo it using toggle. I am able to do it just for the first element of the list. How do I apply for second element and onward since class List. toggle works only with query Selector which selects only the first element of an array.
I am a beginner at JavaScript.

Comment: So how are you doing it? Show that code. So querySelector selects the first element, querySelectorAll matches all the elements

Comment: var list= document.querySelector('li');

  

  
  function upon(){
   
   document.querySelector("li").classList.toggle("done");
    }
  
   list.addEventListener("click",upon);

Comment: by this method i am able to do it just for first element i.e. notebook. if i use queryselectorAll classList. toggle doesnt work also i cant use an array with addEventListener

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Comment: so it means i have to assign id to all of them and then run the JS code for all of them separately?

Comment: There is no bulk way to update so you select all and loop over it.

Comment: tried the loop, still not working.

Comment: cannot figure out a way to jump on to the next element even in the loop. because if i use index [] brackets for iterating to next index element the classList.toggle dont work

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to use `querySelectorAll`, not just `querySelector`, since this only selects the first item, as you already noticed ;)

Here is an example that toggles the class when you click on each item:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((listItem) => {
    listItem.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.target.classList.toggle('done');
    });
});
```